# Flutter - How get context from MockRepository?

Tags: flutter

I'm making an example with flutter and I've come across a question mark. In my project I have implemented dependency injection and I have two classes to get data one for production and testing with local data (Mock). The problem is that the local data I have stored in a json file and when I implement the functionality "fetchProducts" I do not know how to get the Context to load the json... I hope you can help me, thanks.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:graphqllapp/data/product_data.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class MockProductRepository implements ProductRepository {

  @override
  Future<List<Product>> fetchProducts() async {
    // TODO: implement fetchUsers
    String data = await 
    DefaultAssetBundle.of(????).loadString("mockdata/data.json");
    var jsonResult = json.decode(data);
    return new Future.value(products);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use `rootBundle` which is the default value of DefaultAssetBundle

```
rootBundle.loadString("mockdata/data.json");
```